# Error in Sabre SOAP Error : USG_COULD_NOT_COMPLETE_REQUEST

Tags: soap, sabre

We just started developing our own sabre app and we are trying to create a session to proceed with other services.

But an exception returned  :
com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.general.USG_COULD_NOT_COMPLETE_REQUEST

This is the code used :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:eb='http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema'>
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand='1' eb:version='1.0'>
            <eb:ConversationId>*myConversationId*</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type='urn:x12.org:IO5:01'>999999</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type='urn:x12.org:IO5:01'>123123</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:Service eb:type='OTA'>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2016-04-06T01:14:12Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:TimeToLive>2016-04-06T02:14:12Z</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext' xmlns:wsu='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility'>
            <wsse:UsernameToken> 
                <wsse:Username>*Username*</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>*Password*</wsse:Password>
                <Organization>IPCC;</Organization>
                <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain> 
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand='1' eb:version='1.0'>
            <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xlink:href='cid:rootelement' xlink:type='simple'/>
        </eb:Manifest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And here is the returned response :

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns:mstns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:app1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:app2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" id="Envelope" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
<xs:attribute name="mustUnderstand" msdata:Prefix="soap-env" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Envelope" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US" msdata:Prefix="soap-env">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element ref="app1:PartyId"/>
<xs:element name="Header" msdata:Prefix="soap-env">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element ref="app2:Security" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element ref="app1:MessageHeader"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Body" msdata:Prefix="soap-env">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Fault" msdata:Prefix="soap-env" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="faultcode" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="faultstring" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="detail" form="unqualified">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="StackTrace" form="unqualified" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:mstns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:app2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:app1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<xs:element name="Security" msdata:Prefix="wsse" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:mstns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:app1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:app2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" targetNamespace="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
<xs:element name="PartyId" msdata:Prefix="eb" nillable="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent msdata:Prefix="eb" msdata:ColumnName="PartyId_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute name="type" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="MessageHeader" msdata:Prefix="eb">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="CPAId" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1"/>
<xs:element name="ConversationId" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2"/>
<xs:element name="Action" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="3"/>
<xs:element name="From" msdata:Prefix="eb" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element ref="PartyId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="To" msdata:Prefix="eb" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element ref="PartyId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Service" msdata:Prefix="eb" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent msdata:Prefix="eb" msdata:ColumnName="Service_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute name="type" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="MessageData" msdata:Prefix="eb" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="MessageId" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Timestamp" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="RefToMessageId" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="version" msdata:Prefix="eb" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute ref="mstns:mustUnderstand"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header diffgr:id="Header1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenHeader_Id="0">
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"/>
<eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" diffgr:id="MessageHeader1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenMessageHeader_Id="0" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" msdata:hiddenHeader_Id="0">
<eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
<eb:ConversationId>www.tiitco.com10:16</eb:ConversationId>
<eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action>
<eb:From diffgr:id="From1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenFrom_Id="0" msdata:hiddenMessageHeader_Id="0">
<eb:PartyId diffgr:id="PartyId1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" eb:type="URI" msdata:hiddenFrom_Id="0">123123</eb:PartyId>
</eb:From>
<eb:To diffgr:id="To1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenTo_Id="0" msdata:hiddenMessageHeader_Id="0">
<eb:PartyId diffgr:id="PartyId2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" eb:type="URI" msdata:hiddenTo_Id="0">999999</eb:PartyId>
</eb:To>
<eb:Service diffgr:id="Service1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" eb:type="OTA" msdata:hiddenMessageHeader_Id="0">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
<eb:MessageData diffgr:id="MessageData1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenMessageHeader_Id="0">
<eb:MessageId>b00c9239-c921-4983-a8ed-831732f54b84@176</eb:MessageId>
<eb:Timestamp>2016-04-06T07:19:41</eb:Timestamp>
<eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId>
</eb:MessageData>
</eb:MessageHeader>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body diffgr:id="Body1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenBody_Id="0">
<soap-env:Fault diffgr:id="Fault1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenFault_Id="0" msdata:hiddenBody_Id="0">
<faultcode xmlns="">soap-env:Server.SystemFailure</faultcode>
<faultstring xmlns="">SOAPException: Could not complete the request</faultstring>
<detail xmlns="" diffgr:id="detail1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" msdata:hiddenFault_Id="0">
<StackTrace>
com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.general.USG_COULD_NOT_COMPLETE_REQUEST
</StackTrace>
</detail>
</soap-env:Fault>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Does anyone have an idea on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The returned response looks more like a schema declaration in an xsd file.
Is that what you are getting back?

Anyway, the error USG_COULD_NOT_COMPLETE_REQUEST is included on the error codes list:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/status_codes_and_errors

What is the endpoint you are trying to hit?
Customer Acceptance Testing/CERT? 
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments

Are you using a SOAP client tool? Any language?
More info will help.

Comment: Hello fcarreno,
yes  i am using test environment at below URL:
https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com

yes i am using SOAP, c# language

Comment: One more thing. It seems you are not sending the proper message body.
Can you try adding this to your soap body (remove the eb:Manifest element altogether and replace with the below element)?

<SessionCreateRQ>
         <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="YourIPCC"/>
         </POS>
      </SessionCreateRQ>

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an authentication error of some sorts. Here is some working XML for creating a session, compare. Like fcarreno said you are likely missing the PseudoCityCode node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">*or</PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId>X2TH</CPAId>
         <ConversationId>1473816876</ConversationId>
         <Service type="sabreXML">SessionCreateRQ</Service>
         <Action>SessionCreateRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1473816876</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2016-09-14T01:34:36</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2016-09-14T02:34:36</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>*user</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>*pass</wsse:Password>
            <Organization>*ipcc</Organization>
            <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <SessionCreateRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11">
         <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="*ipcc" />
         </POS>
      </SessionCreateRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```